# Why does convolution via multiplication in the frequency domain produce unexpected results MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, fft, convolution, frequency-domain

I'm trying to convolve a rectangular pulse with itself by taking the Fourier transform, squaring it, and then taking the inverse Fourier transform. I realize there is a conv() function but I would prefer to do it in the frequency domain for future, more complex problems. My problem is that when I do this, it does not produce a triangular function as expected. The code I'm using is below:

```
clc

clear all

x=-5:.01:5;

y=rectangularPulse(x);

Y=fft(y);

H=Y.^2;

h=ifft(H);

plot(x,h)
```

Comment: You probably just need an `fftshift` here or there

Comment: Just because MATLAB is case-sensitive, does not mean that having single-letter variables distinguished only by case is a good idea.  I would suggest `yn`, `Yf`, `Hf`, `hn`, then there is no possibility of confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You need to zeropad in order to ensure that the convolution is linear. Currently you are performing a circular convolution. Try something like this:

```
y = ones(100,1);    
N = length(y);
Nfft = 2*length(y) - 1;

Y=fft(y,Nfft);
H=Y.^2;
h=ifft(H);
plot(h);
```

Comment: This produces a triangle pulse as it should, however it is centered at 100 and has an amplitude of 100. It should be centered at 0 and have an amplitude of 1. How can I achieve this? Also keeping in mind that the power Y is raised to should be able to be arbitrary, not necessarily 2.

Comment: I didn't bother defining a time axis since it's not necessary to answer your question. I simply plotted things as a function of sample number. As for the amplitude, the peak of triangle will be equal to the area in the rectangular pulse. Since I didn't normalize the result, this will be equal to 1 * 100 = 100. I get the feeling that you don't really understand what convolution is. May I suggest that you reread your text and then post back  here afterwards if you have any remaining questions.

Comment: I understand exactly what convolution is, and yes, defining an x-axis is in fact necessary to answer my question otherwise the triangle function isn't centered at 0 as it should be. Also in your answer, you did not define y correctly as it should be a rect function with a width of 1, not 100.

Comment: @DavidWebb Your question was why you were getting unexpected results. I told you why and also gave you an example that illustrated what you were doing wrong. If you don't like it, then don't use it. Also, if you understood what convolution is, we wouldn't be having this discussion. Good luck.